# Remove horizontal scroll bar and use 100% width - using bootstrap-table library

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using the [bootstrap-table library](https://bootstrap-table.com).

How can I remove horizontal scroll bar and use 100% width.  Currently the bootstrap-table component is creating horizontal scroll bars and "Stretching" the columns.  I would like to remove the horizontal scrollbar and have the table take up the width of the current browser window.

Here is an example with the horizontal scrollbar:

```html
<table
  data-toggle="table"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-columns="true">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tr-class-1">
      <th data-field="name" rowspan="2" data-valign="middle">Name</th>
      <th colspan="3">Detail</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-class-2">
      <th data-field="star" data-custom-attribute="star">Stars</th>
      <th data-field="forks" data-custom-attribute="forks">Forks</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
      <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1" data-title="bootstrap table" data-object='{"key": "value"}'>
      <td id="td-id-1" class="td-class-1" data-title="bootstrap table">
        <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table" target="_blank">bootstrap-table</a>
      </td>
      <td data-value="526">8827</td>
      <td data-text="122">3603</td>
      <td data-i18n="Description">An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3)
      </td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-2">
        <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select" target="_blank">multiple-select</a>
      </td>
      <td>1615</td>
      <td>623</td>
      <td>A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)
      </td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
      <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-3">
        <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password" target="_blank">bootstrap-show-password</a>
      </td>
      <td>220</td>
      <td>85</td>
      <td>Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap.
      </td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-4" class="tr-class-4">
      <td id="td-id-4" class="td-class-4">
        <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples" target="_blank">bootstrap-table-examples</a>
      </td>
      <td>1734</td>
      <td>1532</td>
      <td>Bootstrap Table Examples</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-5" class="tr-class-5">
      <td id="td-id-5" class="td-class-5">
        <a href="https://github.com/wenzhixin/scutech-redmine" target="_blank">scutech-redmine</a>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>Redmine notification tools for chrome extension.</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
      <td>desc 2</td>
      <td>desc 3</td>
      <td>desc 4</td>
      <td>desc 5</td>
      <td>desc 6</td>
      <td>desc 7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```